# Why is this code taking very long to execute on a server

Tags: c, loadrunner

We use LoadRunner to run performance tests for an application. The tests are generally written in Ansi-C.

We have a simple base64 encoding function:

```
void base64encode(char *src, char *dest, int srcLen, int destLen)
{
  int i=0;
  int slen= srcLen;
  for(i=0;i<slen && i<destLen;i+=3,src+=3)
  {
    *(dest++)=base64encode_lut[(*src&0xFC)>>0x2];
    *(dest++)=base64encode_lut[(*src&0x3)<<0x4|(*(src+1)&0xF0)>>0x4];
    *(dest++)=((i+1)<slen)?base64encode_lut[(*(src+1)&0xF)<<0x2|(*(src+2)&0xC0)>>0x6]:'=';
    *(dest++)=((i+2)<slen)?base64encode_lut[*(src+2)&0x3F]:'=';
  }
  *dest='\0';
}
```

This code when ran on a developer machine (64-bit Windows 10 machines) the code runs in under a sec for a simple image (`srcLen` around 7k).
When ran on the production server (32-bit Windows 2012, VM) the execution takes between 10 to 20 *minutes* for the same image.

Can anyone explain why and how to avoid this issue? I'm not sure if it's LoadRunner or the code to blame.

EDIT: adding the code that is calling the encoding function:

```
long infile; // file pointer
char *buffer; // buffer to read file contents into
char *filename = "DFC_COLOR.jpg"; // file to read
int fileLen; // file size
int bytesRead; // bytes read from file
char *encoded;
int dest_size;

web_set_max_html_param_len("999999999");
infile = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (!infile) {
    lr_error_message("Unable to open file %s", filename);
    return;
}

// get the file length
fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLen = ftell(infile);
fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
lr_log_message("File length is: %9d bytes.", fileLen);


// Allocate memory for buffer to read file
buffer = (char *)malloc(fileLen + 1);
if (!buffer) {
    lr_error_message("Could not malloc %10d bytes", fileLen + 1);
    fclose(infile);
    return;
}

// Read file contents into buffer
bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, fileLen, infile);
if (bytesRead != fileLen)
{
    lr_error_message("File length is %10d bytes but only read %10d bytes", fileLen, bytesRead);
}
else
{
    lr_log_message("Successfully read %9d bytes from file: ", bytesRead);
}
fclose(infile);


// Save the buffer to a loadrunner parameter
lr_save_var(buffer, bytesRead, 0, "fileDataParameter");

// calculate the destination size
dest_size = 1 + ((bytesRead + 2) / 3 * 4);
encoded = (char *)malloc(dest_size);
memset(encoded, 0, dest_size);

// encode the buffer
base64encode(buffer, encoded, bytesRead, dest_size);
```

Comment: Where are the images located? On the network ? Also - Is that the only code you are running? Are you sure the 20 minutes are spent on this code block ?

Comment: @KobyDouek The image is from the network but at the time of the execution the entire file is read into the memory and we're only manipulating the memory. There's no other (our) code that is running and looking at the processor and memory usage, the machine is not fully utilised. I'm sure that exact loop is taking that long because LoadRunner allows debugging and I can pause the execution at any time. It's always in the loop and sometimes it only does around 100 iterations per minute.

Comment: In run-time settings, are you running with full log ?

Comment: @KobyDouek correction: the image is not on the network (though it can be for the production run), it's local copy in the same directory where the binary is.

Comment: Well - That's your problem right there. Copy the image to the load generators on the production and this will solve the problem. Also make sure that you are not running with any logs.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the function or action that calls the base64encode function ?

Comment: @KobyDouek Edited. Also, we tried logging, it's the same with or without detailed logging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137317/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-fedor-hajdu).

Answer (score 0):

Run a single virtual user on a non shared/brokered resource physical machine and see if you have the same performance.  You have no want to determine what your priority and resource pool is within the virtual machine environment.  You could be running on a VM host which is highly overloaded and you are simply having to wait as the hypervisor makes decisions on who gets a given resource set at which time.  Moving a single virtual user to a single hardware host provides a common apples to pears basis (oranges to kumquats) for making your comparison.

LoadRunner also includes an RFC compliant base64 encoding and decoding algorithm as a part of its core set so you do not need to recode this.   Normally this is used as part of the SMTP or DNS virtual users, but you can load the DLL, prototype the functions and move forward.   You can find existing function prototypes in the \include\mic_socket.h header file   Here is a great article on how this is accomplished.   I know the editors are going to scream and demote this as an external link, so you may want to capture the link fast

https://northwaysolutions.com/blog/loadrunner-vugen-encoding-and-decoding-base64/#.WL1vZxLytlc

The other way to handle this is as a Data Format extension.   Decode is already covered as a base extension, so you would only have to handle the encode if you so desired.  Use Google to pull references to Loadrunner, DFE and base64 for the appropriate items.  You can also find a DFE developers guide in your local documentation set, installed with your copy of LoadRunner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The built in base64 doesn't work properly because it only works with strings, and we're encoding an image. As soon as it runs into a termination character it ends (so it only encodes a very small part of the file).

That is the reason why I'm passing the length of the char pointers to the  method instead of just doing strlen().

Comment: Good catch (only on strings)